# Unity ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please I have been on this issue for the last three days. I am trying to instantiate a Unity prefab. I get the following error :

```
ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.
```

I have change the GameObject(Sphere) but I get the same error. Here is my code.

```
public class SEMCell : MonoBehaviour, IAbstractCell{
    SCE[] arrayOfSCEs;
    public SCE scePrefab;
    void IAbstractCell.setMecaModel(AbstractCellMechanicsModel model){
        this.arrayOfSCEs = new SCE[10];
        SCE sce;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sce = Instantiate(scePrefab);
        this.arrayOfSCEs[i] = sce;
    }
}
```

I also linked my GameObject to the prefab property.  Anyone has a clue on the fix ? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Post the `SCE` script and the `IAbstractCell` interface. Also tell us where you are calling `setMecaModel` from; @HimBromBeere `scePrefab` is a public variable and as the screenshot shows, it is set/initialized from the Editor.

Comment: This is probably just a copy/paste issue but you're missing a closing curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

Your prefab should be of type `GameObject` rather than `SCE`.

Change `public SCE scePrefab;` to `public GameObject scePrefab;`

and

`sce = Instantiate(scePrefab);` to `sce = Instantiate(scePrefab).GetComponent<SCE>();`

Comment: Hi Aj_. I tried as you said but I've got the same error message. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I know it's the obvious, but did you re-assigned the object in the editor? Also does the prefab has an `SCE` script attached to it?

Comment: Yes. The prefab has an SCE script attached to it.

Comment: That's interesting. Post a screenshot of the prefab and also post the code in the SCE class.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is fine. Whatever is handling an `IAbstractCell` is setting the `scePrefab` field to null.

Try to make your SCE field private and serialized:

```
[SerializeField] private SCE scePrefab;
```

This will show you compiler errors where you're inadvertently setting `scePrefab` to null in other code. Otherwise, you may be setting it to null anywhere inside `SEMCell`, like an `Await` or `Start`. Try searching your code for `scePrefab = null`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is fine. Two possibilities:

Whatever is handling an `IAbstractCell` is setting the `scePrefab` field to null.

Try to make your SCE field private and serialized:

```
[SerializeField] private SCE scePrefab;
```

This will show you compiler errors where you're inadvertently setting `scePrefab` to null in other code. Otherwise, you may be setting it to null anywhere inside `SEMCell`, like an `Await` or `Start`. Try searching your code for `scePrefab = null`.

Or,  you are destroying the object that the SCE script is attached to. Make that object a prefab and drag-and-drop the prefab into the slot in your editor.